# 2 heaters on same circuit

Tags: electrical

My wife bought 2 heaters for bird baths. One is [60 watt](https://naturehouseinc.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=235_116_84&products_id=245&zenid=3vatsc58psmcscnkp2mip6mq65) and the other is [80 watts](https://order.wbu.com/shop/bird-baths-&-houses/bird-baths-&-water/wbu-80-watt-bird-bath-heater). One lists requirements of a 16-gauge or better extension cord with GFCI outlet. Any other advice? Can these 2 be used on the same circuit (I'm guessing a 15amp breaker but haven't checked)? If we also want an outdoor light on the same circuit, can we use a splitter on the receptacle with the 60 watt heater or are we asking for trouble?

Comment: If you dont have GFCI (RCD) within your fusebox then you will need it on your extension lead. From the viewpoint of a European person, I find it surprising for developed world not to have them as standard. (being standard in west/central Europe except for Hungary since bit after the World war 2). The benefits of it for safety are so majour that its a very worthy investment

Comment: Good point, @Tomas. Here in the States, they've been code required on any outdoor outlet for about 30 years. There are a _lot_ of older houses that don't have them, though.

Comment: +1 just for thinking to ask instead of plugging it in and hoping for the best, then complaining if/when it fails.

Comment: @FreeMan I've always heard to be careful about indoor heaters, but I'm guessing they must use a lot more current.

Comment: Reading between the lines - a bird bath heater is there to stop a bird bath from freezing solid outside in the winter ?  So whatever you do, most of the cord along with the final plug/socket(s) will be exposed to water, freezing temperatures, therefore ice, and possibly salt/sand.   You will need to protect al parts of it, and also check regularly that the heater is not running dry.

Comment: I would agree that an indoor space heater will have a lot higher current draw because it's trying to heat a room to ~70°F or higher, while the bird bath heater is keeping a reasonably small amount of water above 32°F. However, depending on how cold it is outside, that could require a fair bit of heating effort...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 16 gauge cord will have no trouble running both of those heaters and a light off any conventional outlet, assuming the circuit isn't loaded down with a bunch of other devices. Even if it's 150 feet long, it will still be capable of about 770 watts safely, and you're describing a total of something around 200 watts. Pay more attention to making certain that it's on a GFCI and that your connections are well protected from water.

Answer (score 9):

60 watts + 80 watts is only 140 watts, just over 1 amp at 120 volts.   The overkill on the extension cord gauge was mostly likely written by lawyers.    Regarding GFCI: Given that you are combining water and electricity....what could go wrong? (sarcasm intended).  In this case GFCI is **CRITICAL**. Very important to properly protect those with GFCI.

Answer (score 6):

60 W / 120 V = 0.5 amps.

80 W / 120 V = 0.66 amps.

0.5 amps + 0.66 amps is 1.16 amps.   This is less than 15 amps.

16 gauge is the minimum legal size of extension cord per UL 817.  It is approved to 15A when used in the manners in which cordage is legal to use per NEC 110.3(B), 400.7 and 400.8.  Which is to say in the open air, with readily available air cooling, and not buried in walls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of these (60W + 80W + typical lighting) can all be on one circuit. A few considerations:

- GFCI

If you already have the circuit protected by a GFCI then you're set. If not, you can add it at the outdoor receptacle, at an indoor receptacle on the same circuit (must be prior to this receptacle in the wiring sequence) or at the breaker. Breaker/GFCI is most expensive and sometimes easiest, sometimes hardest (depending on the panel situation). Breaker/receptacle outside seems most logical *but* keep in mind that the GFCI electronics will not last as long outside (hot/cold/wind/rain) as inside.

- Weather Resistant/In Use Cover

Any outdoor receptacle should be weather resistant (won't last forever, but will help some) and have an *in use cover* which helps to protect from rain.

- Hardwire vs. Plug-in

The birdbath heaters are plug-in (one very clearly from the picture, I assume the other is as well). But lights can be plug-in or hardwired. I would seriously consider hardwired connections for lighting, unless you expect to move or change them on a regular basis. However, hardwired connections outdoors require wiring methods that can handle wet locations. This means either certain types of cable, but *not* ordinary NM cable (a.k.a., Romex) or wiring in conduit. A hardwired light can be chained off of the receptacle as long as it is relatively low power, which is pretty much guaranteed with LEDs, unless you want to light up your backyard like a baseball stadium.

- Extension Cords

16 AWG is more than enough for a few hundred watts. But you need to make sure that any extension cords used on a regular basis outside (and I suspect these will sit out for weeks or months at a time) are designed for outdoor use. A standard lamp extension cord will handle the current but will *not* stand up to well to rain or critters. Actually, no extension cord will last forever with too many critters, but thick insulation helps.